# runtime error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set, example from MS office website

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to extract data from MS-excel graph using macro given on MS excel [website](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/300643)

Here is the code

```
Sub GetChartValues()
   Dim NumberOfRows As Integer
   Dim X As Object
   Counter = 2

   ' Calculate the number of rows of data.
   NumberOfRows = UBound(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values)

   Worksheets("ChartData").Cells(1, 1) = "X Values"

   ' Write x-axis values to worksheet.
   With Worksheets("ChartData")
      .Range(.Cells(2, 1), _
      .Cells(NumberOfRows + 1, 1)) = _
      Application.Transpose(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues)
   End With

   ' Loop through all series in the chart and write their values to
   ' the worksheet.
   For Each X In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
      Worksheets("ChartData").Cells(1, Counter) = X.Name

      With Worksheets("ChartData")
         .Range(.Cells(2, Counter), _
         .Cells(NumberOfRows + 1, Counter)) = _
         Application.Transpose(X.Values)
      End With


      Counter = Counter + 1
   Next

End Sub
```

Where is the error in this code?

Comment: Have you debug the code? On which line it is giving the error?

Comment: On this line 
    'NumberOfRows = UBound(ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values)'

Comment: Two things: Do you actually have a WorkSheet labelled "ChartData" and do you have a Chart that is Active? There are a few steps you need to follow on the link you provided

Comment: yes I have worksheet labeled 'ChartData'. And instead of activeChart I have used method given by @Paresh in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VB Complier will not know which ActiveChart you are talking about. Hence you need to **set** the chart object first and then try to use it.

Check this code:

```
Dim mychart As ChartObject

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set mychart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 1")

With mychart.Chart
   'do stuff here
End With
```